# How to get product image and URL in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, product-images

This is my observer:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    $order = $this->_orderRepositoryInterface->get($orderIds[0]);
    $items =$order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $productQuantity = array();
    $productPrice = array();
    $productName = array();
    $productIds = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $productIds[]= $item->getProductId();
        $productName[]= $item->getSku(); 
        $productPrice[] = $item->getPrice();
        $productQuantity[]= floor($item->getQtyOrdered());
    }
}
```

How can I get the product image and product URL from the item?

Comment: Which event you catched?

Comment: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This way may not the best way to get a product image.

Inject `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory` in the constructor.

```
protected $_productRepositoryFactory;

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory
) {            
    $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
}
```

We can get the image:

```
$product = $this->_productRepositoryFactory->create()
    ->getById($item->getProductId());
$product->getData('image');
$product->getData('thumbnail');
$product->getData('small_image');
```

Comment: your answer is right but what shoild i do if i have more than one product in cart how can i show more than one product image

Comment: ok i got it @khoa. if i have more than one produc image. thanks alot

Comment: This is not working. Value returned is some kind of string like this "/w/s/wsh10-orange_main.jpg"

Comment: @piavgh it's the path to image: `pub/media/catalog/product`

Comment: so how do i use /w/s/wsh10-orange_main.jpg in <img src="" /> attribute so i can load the actual image

Comment: I mean, without doing a special method like public function getProductImageUrl( $product, $image_type = 'product_page_image_small' )
    {
        $imageBlock =  $this->blockFactory->createBlock( 'Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct' );
        return $imageBlock->getImage( $product, $image_type )->getImageUrl();
    }

Comment: This isn't get the full cache path image. Ex: domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/{cache_id}/w/j/wj23.jpg

Answer (score 39):

If you need to return a product URL it should look like this:

```
//todo get product object $product 

$objectManager =\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$helperImport = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$imageUrl = $helperImport->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                ->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage()) // image,small_image,thumbnail
                ->resize(380)
                ->getUrl();
echo $imageUrl;
```

Comment: Best, simple answer

Comment: This answer is exactly what am I looking for. Thanks

Comment: **You should not resize like that**, but do more definition in the *view.xml* of your theme, and use its id as the second parameter of the helper: 

The way you do it, if you delete the catalog/product/cache directory, and ask for your "380" image directly in browser, Magento will not regenerate it automatically: he is not aware that this format exists and won't do so.

Answer (score 27):

If you want the published/cache frontend URL of an image for a specific store view (like I did) this is working for me:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
 */
protected $appEmulation;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $productRepositoryFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
 */
protected $imageHelperFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $helperFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory
)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
    $this->productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
    $this->imageHelperFactory = $imageHelperFactory;
}
```

Then, wherever you need to get the image frontend URL:

```
$sku = "my-sku";
// get the store ID from somewhere (maybe a specific store?)
$storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
// emulate the frontend environment
$this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
// load the product however you want
$product = $this->productRepositoryFactory->create()->get($sku);
// now the image helper will get the correct URL with the frontend environment emulated
$imageUrl = $this->imageHelperFactory->create()
  ->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl();
// end emulation
$this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

You can select other images types besides `product_thumbnail_image`: see `magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml` for a list of available product images, or create your own in a `view.xml` file.

Comment: WTF? that is just sick :D

Comment: Just tried this solution and I'm not getting any errors, though the returned URL doesn't exist and the string is empty. I've tried with 'product_base_image', 'product_small_image' and 'product_thumbnail_image', none of which work. Can you advise please? Or is there an efficient way to do this using the product repository? As I am already loading that elsewhere in my block.

Answer (score 8):

That's the way I did. it's quite efficient and clean:

1) First, you need to inject the following classes:

```
protected $_storeManager;
protected $_appEmulation;
protected $_blockFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation)
{
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    $this->_appEmulation = $appEmulation;
}
```

2) Then, create a getImageUrl method with the code below:

```
protected function getImageUrl($product, string $imageType = '')
{
    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    $this->_appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

    $imageBlock =  $this->_blockFactory->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
    $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, $imageType);
    $imageUrl = $productImage->getImageUrl();

    $this->_appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

    return $imageUrl;
}
```

Note: The "appEmulation" code is only necessary when you making this call from the **admin** or for an **API**. Otherwise, you will get the error below (or similar):

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'webapi_rest/_view/en_AU/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg'
```

3) Call the getImageUrl passing the product object and the type of image you want (based on your **view.xml** file)

```
...
$smallImage = $this->getImageUrl($productObject, 'product_page_image_small');
...
```

Comment: this code throw error "Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: productObject in /mnt/BLOCKSTORAGE/home/59434482.cloudwaysapps.com/public_html/app/code/Themename/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/customer_order_custom.phtml on line 99

What is the $productObject varaiable pass?

Answer (score 4):

For gettting custom image url I used this code. So if the image does not exits it will load the default theme image.

```
$product = $block->getProduct();

$productImageAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute('product_banner_image');

if ($productImageAttr && $productImageAttr->getValue() != 'no_selection') {

    $productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
    ->init($product, 'product_banner_image')
    ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());

    $imageUrl = $productImage->getUrl();

} else {

    $imageUrl = $this->getViewFileUrl('images/cat-img1.jpg'); // Theme/web/images

}
```

Comment: This isn't get the full cache path image. Ex: domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/{cache_id}/w/j/wj23.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Since this seems to be the top search results and none of the answers really worked for me, here's a simple helper class to get an product's thumbnail image from the cache:

```
<?php

namespace Mobweb\Core\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /** @var ImageHelper */
    private $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @param ImageHelper $imageHelper
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        ImageHelper $imageHelper,
        Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     */
    public function getImageUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        return $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the cached image url:

Construct

```
/** 
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image 
 */
private $imageHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
 */
protected $appEmulation;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation
){
    $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
    $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
}
```

Get an image

```
public function getBaseImageUrl(ProductInterface $product, $storeId)
{
    $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

    // 'product_base_image' or any image code from vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\etc\view.xml
    $url = $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')->getUrl();

    $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

    return $url;
}
```

Get all images

```
public function getBaseImageUrl(ProductInterface $product, $storeId)
{
    $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

    $urls = [];
    foreach($product->getMediaGalleryEntries() as $image){
        // 'product_base_image' or any image code from vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\etc\view.xml
        $baseImage = $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl();

        $urls[] = $baseImage;
    }

    $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

    return $urls;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get the first (single) getUrl() function to give me a result (it always returned the placeholder as image for this product.)
I used a combination of the two examples (single/multiple) to get an image for me:
`$this->imageHelper->init($product, $imageIdString)->setImageFile($product->getImage())->getUrl();`

Answer (score 2):

My way works with watermarks and is same as magento using.

DI:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder */
private $imageBuilder;
```

Method returns string (placeholder):

```
private function getProductImageUrl(Product $product): string
{
    $image = $this->imageBuilder
        ->setProduct($product)
        ->setImageId('product_small_image')
        ->setAttributes([])
        ->create();

    return $image->getImageUrl();
}
```

Method returns null or string:

```
private function getProductImageUrlOrNull(Product $product): ?string
{
    if (empty($product->getImage()) || $product->getImage() === SitemapResourceProduct::NOT_SELECTED_IMAGE) {
        return null;
    }

    return $this->getProductImageUrl($product);
}
```

Comment: This is successfully in get the full cache path image, but this code is created it's own cache_id. Ex: domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/{cache_id}/w/j/wj23.jpg

Comment: Actually, the `cache_id` is depend on what is your `image_id`, in my case, i transfer `setImageId("product_page_image_medium")` instead of `setImageId('product_small_image')`, and that solved my problem. You can check other `image_id` at `magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get base image,

```
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

Comment: This isn't get the full cache path image. Ex: domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/{cache_id}/w/j/wj23.jpg

Answer (score 2):

In multi-store mode and using store view code in the URL's. You can get the product's full image URL using this method:

```
$productId  = 12; //eg;
$productFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');                            
$product        = $productFactory->create()->load($productId);
$attribute      = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('image');
$imageUrl       = $attribute->getFrontend()->getUrl($product);
```

Comment: This isn't get the full cache path image. Ex: domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/{cache_id}/w/j/wj23.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You Can direct use this on `.phtml`

```
$this->helper('Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images')
->getBaseUrl().'catalog/product'.$_product->getImage();
```

Comment: This isn't get the full cache path image. Ex: domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/{cache_id}/w/j/wj23.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    $file = fopen('sku.csv', 'r'); // set path to the CSV file
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $getUrl=$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/stockupdate-new.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $headers[]=array('sku','name','image','addtional_images');

    $header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row

    $required_data_fields = 2;
$counter =0;
    while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 40000, ",") ) {

        $data = array();
        $data = array_combine($header, $row);
        $sku = $data['sku'];
        // print_r($sku);
        // die();
    try{
        $product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->get($sku);
        $get_sku=$product->getSku();
        $name=$product->getName();
        $imageUrl='https://ebygghandel.se/media/catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
        $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
        // addtional_images
        $getPathImages=array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($images as $child){
            if($i == 0){
                $getPathImages[]=$child->getUrl(); 
            }else{
                $getPathImages2[$i]=$child->getUrl();
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $getPathImages=implode(',', $getPathImages2);
        $headers[]=array($get_sku,$name,$imageUrl,$getPathImages);
    }catch (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {                  
        $logger->info('Error importing product sku: '.$sku.'. '.$e->getMessage());
        } 
}
    $fp = fopen("getImagePath.csv","w"); //first the read the file and header and create the data in csv
// $fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
    foreach ($headers as $line) {
        fputcsv($fp, $line);
    }
    fclose($fp);   

?>
```