# How to load multiple id's for products in magento 2 using objectManager?

Tags: magento2, product, object-manager

I want to load `array(2,6,7)` of products id's using **objectManager** and
get details of the product. I found most of the Magento-1.9 solutions.
Is there anything for Magento 2?

I found this,

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}  
?>
```

but how to load my array product ids?

Answer (score 6):

Try below code use `in`

```
 <?php
    $porIds=array(2,6,7);
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    /** Apply filters here */
    $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $porIds));

                echo '<pre>';print_r($collection->getData());
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 2
            [attribute_set_id] => 15
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 24-MB04
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2017-11-03 11:21:57
            [updated_at] => 2017-11-03 11:21:57
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 6
            [attribute_set_id] => 15
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 24-MB02
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2017-11-03 11:21:58
            [updated_at] => 2017-11-03 11:21:58
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 7
            [attribute_set_id] => 15
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 24-UB02
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2017-11-03 11:21:58
            [updated_at] => 2017-11-03 11:21:58
        )

)
```

Comment: hi @Qaisar, can we use addFieldToFilter  with sku instead of entity_id

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
<?php 
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$products = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('product_id1','product_id2'));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($products->getData());
?>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. how to get image and url of  those product?

Comment: This one will help for you you need to load the product id, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137057/how-to-get-product-image-and-url-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

```
$porductIds=array(2,6,7);
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $collectionByIds = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collectionByIds->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $porductIds));
    $collectionByIds->load();

    foreach ($collectionByIds as $collection) :
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection->getName());
    endforeach;
```