# Get cached thumbnail image url in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

I need to get the url of a product cached thumbnail image.
This is my code:

```
$appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($_POST['store_id'], \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

$image = $helperImage->create()->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')
                    ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                    ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                    ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
                    ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                    ->resize(245,300);

$temp[] = $image->getUrl();

$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

The path I get is `http://domain.com/pub/static/version1522319407/frontend/Vendor/theme_child/it_IT/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg`

How can I get the cached thumbnail image url?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One tip I can give is that the Product Images Cache in pub/media/catalog/product/cache. I'll research more and give you feedback. Try : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137057

Comment: I just tried your code and am getting a cached image.
‌https://domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/thumbnail/400x400/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/2/0/201305-efefef.jpg