# Magento 2 PHP Foreach loop help!

Tags: magento2, php, orders, products, history

I'm trying to display the images of products on each order item, so far I have the image pulling through but it's only one of 3 product images.

It's also displaying them on every order in the order history, but they should only display the correct images per order.

Below is my code, any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php $_orders = $block->getOrders(); ?>
  <?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)): ?>
    <div class="myOrders">
      <h2>My Orders</h2>
        <div class="order">
          <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
            <?php
              $orderId = $_order->getId();
               $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
               $items = $order->getAllItems();
               foreach ($items as $itemId => $_item){
                 $_item->getProductId();
                 $_item->getName();
                 $_item->getPrice();
                 $_item->getSku();
                 $_item->getQtyToInvoice();
                 $_product = $_item->getProduct($_item->getProductId());
                 $imageBlock =  $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
                 $productImages[] = $imageBlock->getImage($_product, 'category_page_grid');
               }
             ?>
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                 <h4><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                 <h4><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h4><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <?php foreach($productImages as $productImage): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $productImage->toHtml()  ?></a>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT**

After following one of the solutions on this post I've now got all images pulling through but they are being duplicated on each orders.

See screenshot:
[image]

Kind of hard to see I know but the second order in the order history also has the first orders product images which don't exist in that order, so therefore should not be displaying.

Comment: You better post the code in writing instead of the image, it allows others to copy your code and test it in their machines if you need help, help them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please don't use directly the **objectManager** in your phtml, do instead some functions in your block, then you get them is you phtml exemple: `$block->getFuntion();`
2. For all products images, try `$images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();`
3. You loop the images:

   ```
   foreach($images as $image) {
       echo $image->getUrl();
   }
   ```

Comment: I never really knew how to use functions outside of the block, so thank you for informing me about that c: I will amend my code

Answer (score 0):

Kindly review your code. For calling images you need to use the 
below URL examples : [How to get product image and url in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137057/how-to-get-product-image-and-url-in-magento-2)

Suggested above url will surely solve your issue and you can find best way to call images. let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't post code as an image in future questions...

Regarding your code, you assign $productImage new every time you loop $items, which basically means that you only get the last image every time.

Change your code to:

```
$productImages[] = $imageBlock->getImage($_product, 'category_page_grid');
```

And below where you want to display it:

```
foreach($productImages as $productImage) {
    // display code comes here
}
```

As noted by prince, you should not use the object manager directly.

Also, you don't want to use the `load()` function, because it is deprecated. The correct way to load a product would be using the `ProductRepository->get()` method (read about Magento 2 service contracts in the developer documentation).

Also, you **never** want to `load()` **anything** inside a **loop**.

Also, `$item` should have a method `getProduct()` that you can simply call to get the product.

Comment: The reason I posted the code as a image is because it wouldn't paste properly into the code snippet, I do apologise. In my response to Prince I mention that I never knew how to use functions outside of the block, but now I do I will update my code. I'll attempt to get it working, thank you c:

Comment: I've managed to get it working with your code, however the images duplicate across all orders, despite the order not having those products within the item. I've update the code on post, if you could take a look that'd be great thank you c:

Comment: oh sry. add `$productImages = [];` before `foreach(items as item)` loop