# Product Atttribute Image

Tags: magento2, attributes, image

How to get **`attribute image`** in **Magento2** using product object?

Answer (score 0):

Just inject this `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory` in your constructor.

```
protected $_productRepositoryFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory
) {

    $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
}
```

Get the image this way:

```
$product = $this->_productRepositoryFactory->create()->getById($item->getProductId());
$product->getData('image');
```

reference [Get product image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137057/how-to-get-product-image-and-url-in-magento-2/137064#137064)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
$image= $product->getData('attr_code');
```

Comment: i want attribute image not product image